# Is architecting a .net & sql server data mngmt app where app sql is stored in table a sound approach?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm building a data management app using vs .net and SQL server.  The app will have many selects, inserts and updates.  Instead of having the SQL hard coded in the app, I've created a table, 'tblobjsql',  with varchar(MAX) columns which contain the various parts of the needed sql.  I then have a stored proc with input parm of object id which does a select on 'tblobjsql', takes the return values, constructs the needed sql and performs the app action or returns a dataset to the .net app.  I've tested and it all works as expected.  This approach seems sound with many potential benefits.  Amazing expert advice on this site... should I continue with this approach or are there unseen dangers ahead?

Comment: Surely your .net app needs to know the number of columns and their names in the results set, so how is this more beneficial than - for example - just using stored procedures to return your results?

Comment: So, you're reinventing views and stored procedures (maybe UDFs too), but less functional? There are already ways to stored SQL in a database. Storing it in a user table seems to be among the worst of options for doing it.

Comment: In the .net app, I can dynamically get the number of columns and their names.  There will probably be places in the app where I will need to know the exact column name and have to handle a differently.  If I have the sql in a table as described, I can do all the formatting and column additions/deletions without touching code.  If I do a new app release, I can just add a new row to the sql table that the new app uses while the old row still exists for previous app version.  I could use views but this approach seems efficient although a bit non-standard, outside the box.

Comment: @mrmojo I've seen similar approaches before. It's certainly an option. However, while you possibly gain in deployment flexibility, that can also be a negative. This approach is probably ok if all you're doing is running reports, for example, and I use a similar approach in this case (although I use stored procs instead). But bear in mind that you miss out on the benefits of closer coupling with the data, such as you get from an ORM like Entity Framework, which are more important when dealing with application data.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G – Sincere thank you!!  The app will not be doing actions on large quantities of data and not functionally dependent on the data integrity… just moving user defined data around, formatting a bit and staging for an external app.  I also intend to have both a Windows version and a ASP.NET version so I’m thinking the most efficient way to do that is to have as much logic in the database as possible.  Thank you for your advice… I’ll study up on the ORM Entity Framework approach.